# Автоувеличение счетчика в базе данных

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте, ХэшКод.

У меня есть таблица, в которой есть число 0 (для примера), и мне нужно, чтобы оно каждые 14 часов автоматически увеличивалось на 1 и так у всех записей. Как так сделать или в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоватся, а зачем это вам надо? Может решение проблемы лежит в другой области?

Answer (score 2):

Создай JOB, в котором напиши обычный update с нужными тебе изменениями, а в настройках JOB-а укажи частоту вызова и все.

Comment: А можно подробнее?

Comment: В БД Oracle это делается так: http://citforum.ru/database/oracle/scheduler/

Comment: У меня MySql база.

Comment: На здоровье [MySql Планировщик][1]


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/123391/

Answer (score 1):

Каждые 14 часов, с помощью [cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) например, делайте запрос к БД

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `counter_name` = `counter_name`+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно, какие инструменты вы используете. Может вы делаете десктопное приложение (на C#, например), может Web-приложение. Я остановлюсь на последнем, так как мне кажется, что вам надо именно это.

Сделать такую штуковину можно просто: для этого вам надо каждые 14 часов где-нибудь оставлять метку времени (можно в текстовом файле), в которую был произведен последний инкремент. Затем каждый раз при входе на сайт, скрипт (скорее, PHP) должен будет смотреть ту самую метку и вычитать её из текущей. Потом вам останется лишь преобразовать разность меток времени в часы и проверять, не равна ли она или не более 14, если так, то обновлять метку в том самом файле и инкрементировать определенное значение в БД.

Comment: Да вы правы это php и mysql, но вот беда, а если на сайте никого не будет.

Comment: Ну это будет легко поправить( зная математику =) ). Берем разность меток времени и определяем частное при делителе 14. Берем целую часть частного и инкрементируем столько раз, чему равно частное. Затем берем остаток часного и пишем в файл текущее время + остаток, преобразованный в метку времени.

Comment: если это php, то есть такая тема как cron, в эту сторону и копайте.
при его установке указывается частота вызова, внутри делаете свои query для DB

Comment: @zippp, блин, вы дубок? Тут дело в том, что кто-то должен будет все-таки заходить на сайт для этого инкремента!

Comment: Думаю, это Вы дубок.

Answer (score 0):

Php скрипт еще можно вызывать с помощи `cron`. Он сам автоматический будет вызывать каждое 14 часов. А `php` скрипт потом будет `update`"ом увеличить на единицу значение.